# how to get callback of datasmith runtime?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I'm using unreal blueprint of datasmith to load revit model in runtime. but i don't know out how to emit callback when the model has been load and rendered.
the "Datasmith Destination Actor" has a property of progress, i try to watch that property but no luck.
First, the end value is not 1 but 1.396324 ,
Secondly, event when progress reached 1.396324 the hierarchy has not been rendered completely.

[watch on datasmith runtime actor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbKqw.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with this issue as well. I want to inspect the loaded tree when it is completed.
In addition to the "progress" value, there is a "building" boolean.
It appears there are two phases: loading and building.
During the loading phase, the "building" property starts false and the "progress" property starts increasing. At some point, "building" goes true and "progress" remains constant at a value > 1.
Then the "building" flag goes False again, it seems that the UDatasmith file is loaded and available.